# connect Angular 8 to PHP Bluehost Shared hosting

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess, shared-hosting, bluehost

I'm new in full stack development(I'm using php and Angular 8), and I'm deploying my website now to bluehost, and my httpclient requests(get,post,,) are giving me (404).. I don't know if I should edit .htaccess file to redirect to php file correctly or not..
all my website files are placed in public_html(also read.php and create.php)
and this is a snippet from my service

```
export class ApiService {

  PHP_API_SERVER = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  baseUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  users :User[];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  readPolicies(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/read.php`);
  }

  createPolicy(policy: User): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/create.php`, policy);
  }
}
```

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where is your documentroot folder set in apache config file ? if http://api.example.com/read.php is set inside apache config to server exact document root. ?